# Store specific output to a shell variable

Tags: shell, text-processing, variable, command-substitution

I am looking to store the output of the `svn info` command, more precisely the revision number into a variable for further processing. I just need the `4` stored.

```
$ svn info
[...]
Revision: 4
[...]
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Using awk

awk works well for this:

```
rev=$(svn info | awk '/Revision:/{print $2}')
```

The code above uses *command substitution*, `$(...)`, to capture the output of a command and assign it to a variable.

In the code above, awk reads the output of `svn info` and waits for a line that contains the string `Revision:`. When that line is found, it prints the second field on that line, which is be the revision number.

#### Using sed

It is also possible to do this using sed:

```
rev=$(svn info | sed -n '/Revision:/ s/.* //p')
```

With the `-n` option, sed will only print when we explicitly ask it to.  `/Revision:/` selects lines that contain the string `Revision:`.  For those lines, a substitution command is performed that removes all characters up to the last blank on the line and then, due to the `p` option, the line is printed.

#### Using shell

```
while read -r name value
do 
    [ "$name" = Revision: ] && var="$value"
done < <(svn info)
```

The above uses redirection from *process substition*, `< <(...)`, to supply the output of `svn info` to a while loop.  For each iteration of the loop, the first word on the line is assigned to `name` and the rest of the line is assigned to `value`.  If `name` is `Revision:`, then the shell variable `var` is assigned to `value`, which is the revision number.

Many, but not all, shells support process substitution.  When, as above, redirection is combined with process substitution, the space between the two `<` is essential.